# Plotting an inequation in a complex plane!

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have struggled with that one for a long time, but I can't find the solution. The task is to plot that in a complex plane. im desperate for help!

$|z-2| > 2 + Im(Z)$

Comment: Try putting $z = x + iy$

Comment: doesn't get me anywhere sadly

Comment: It will surely take you somewhere if you are willing to move.

Comment: @ArseniyKlimov: show us what you got when plugging $x+iy$.

Comment: after the other comment it got me on the right way, the direction i was moving in was wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ :

$$|z-2|>2+\text{Im}\,z\implies \sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}>2+y\implies (x-2)^2+y^2>4+4y+y^2\implies$$

$$\implies y<\frac{(x-2)^2}4-1$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thank you! that definitely helped me'